# Short story read c. 1960: boy unhappy with his family, dreams of being picked up by his "real parents"

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

One of the short stories in my elementary school reading book (late 50s or early 60s) was about a young boy who was unhappy in his home and family. He constantly fantasized about his "real parents" coming to get him and take him away from his ordinary life. I've searched and searched for the story, thinking it was named something like "All the Duke's Children," but that always takes me down rabbit trails not related to the story I'm thinking of. I do know that sometimes a short story in a reading book was really a selection taken from a larger work and given an arbitrary title, so I may not be able to find it.

Any help?

Comment: Also, take a look at [this guide to asking story ID requests](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561). If there's any other detail you remember, please [edit] your question to add it.

Comment: Some more information might help people answer this. Where did you read it and in what language? Do you remember anything else that might have been in the book? Do any other details, even minor ones, jump out at you?